# In which order yaml-cpp returns data?

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I wrote the following yaml file:

```
linear: [0.0,1.0,10.0,0.05]
linear: [1.0,0.5,5.0,0.05]
rotational: [0.0,6.28,20,0.5]
rotational: [6.28,0.0,20,0.5]
```

and I use [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) to parse it with the following code:

```
YAML::Node sequence = YAML::LoadFile(filename_);
int count = 1;
for (YAML::const_iterator it = sequence.begin(); it != sequence.end(); ++it)
{
  const std::string& name = it->first.as<std::string>();
  const std::vector<double>& parameters = it->second.as<std::vector<double> >();
...
```

if I print `name` and `parameters` values (in the order I get them) the output is:

```
linear: [0,1,10,0.05]
rotational: [6.28,0,20,0.5]
linear: [1,0.5,5,0.05]
rotational: [0,6.28,20,0.5]
```

can someone please explain me what is happening and suggest me how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: It *parses* in the order the source file is written. No other practical possibility exists. How it returns *node sequences* is another matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML maps are not allowed to have [duplicate keys](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764652), so that YAML file is actually illegal. yaml-cpp is simply lenient here and doesn't report an error.

What's more, YAML maps do not specify a [key order](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765608), and so yaml-cpp simply chooses whatever order is most convenient internally to iterate over. It's probably best to assume that *unspecified* order means *random* order, i.e., you can't rely on it.